# NaN showing instead of calculation from node js (express) back end

Tags: javascript, node.js, web, backend, nan

i m just learning express and node js and i was making bmi calculator. every thing is just as the tutorial but my result is getting NaN instead of calculation
heres the code

```
node js
app.get("/bmiCalculator", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/bmiCalculator.html")
})
app.post("/bmiCalculator", (req, res) => {
    var w = parseFloat(req.body.weight)
    var h = parseFloat(req.body.height)
    var bmi = w / (h * h);
    res.send("your bmi is " + bmi)
})


html
</head>
<h1>bmi cal</h1>

<body>
    <form action="/bmiCalculator" method="post">
        <input type="text" placeholder="weight">
        <input type="text" placeholder="height">
        <button type="submit">bmi calculate</button>
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: Have you looked at exactly what `req.body.weight`, `req.body.height` and `w` and `h` are?  This is basic debugging that would likely point you to the problem.  Please do basic debugging BEFORE posting here.

Answer (score 3):

Isn't it just that your form fields are missing a `name` attribute?

Answer (score 0):

On the form,you need to add a name field i.e

```
<input type="text" name="weight" placeholder="weight">
<input type="text" name="height" placeholder="height">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
try this

app.get("/bmiCalculator", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(__dirname, "/bmiCalculator.html")
})
app.post("/bmiCalculator", (req, res) => {
    let w = Number(req.body.weight)
    let h = Number(req.body.height)
   let bmi = Math.round(w / (h * h));
    res.send(`your bmi is ${ bmi}`)
})

since parseFloat() is undefined.
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).